# CS50 Pset4 Edge coding - error of index 601 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

for CS50 Pset4 filters Edges part, https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/ I have the code below and it returns error of

helpers.c:205:216: runtime error: index 601 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'

in the line of

```
RGBTRIPLE array[] = {larger_image[i][j], larger_image[i][j + 1], larger_image[i][j + 2], 
larger_image[i + 1][j], larger_image[i + 1][j + 1], larger_image[i + 1][j + 2], 
larger_image[i + 2][j], larger_image[i + 2][j + 1], larger_image[i + 2][j + 2]};
```

The logic of my code is to create a new image, larger_image with outlines of zero RGB values. In this way , can easily calculate the sobel operator.
Then I create another array of 9 elements with type RGBTRIPLE so i can loop around to add up to he sumproduct of he box. But error got here, I checked the i and j boundary and it seems ok...

can someone help me look into why there is error in the array here?

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE(*edged)[width] = calloc(height, (width) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

    **// create another mirror image with size of height +2 and width + 2 of outline RGB numbers zero**
    RGBTRIPLE(*larger_image)[width] = calloc(height + 2, (width + 2) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));




int i =0;
    int j = 0;
    float blue_final, green_final, red_final;

    for (i = 1; i < height +1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < width + 1; j++)
        {
            larger_image[i][j] = image[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }

    int gx[] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
    int gy[] = {-1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1};

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int blue_x = 0, blue_y = 0, green_x = 0, green_y = 0, red_x = 0, red_y = 0;

        **//create an array of 9 elements easier for me to loop the sumproduct with gx/gy below, error here.**
            RGBTRIPLE array[] = {larger_image[i][j], larger_image[i][j + 1], larger_image[i][j + 2],
 larger_image[i + 1][j], larger_image[i + 1][j + 1], larger_image[i + 1][j + 2], 
larger_image[i + 2][j], larger_image[i + 2][j + 1], larger_image[i + 2][j + 2]};

            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
            {
                blue_x += array[k].rgbtBlue * gx[k];
               
                blue_y += array[k].rgbtBlue * gy[k];
              
                green_x += array[k].rgbtGreen * gx[k];
                green_y += array[k].rgbtGreen * gy[k];
                red_x += array[k].rgbtRed * gx[k];
                red_y += array[k].rgbtRed * gy[k];
            }

            blue_final = sqrt(pow(blue_x, 2) + pow(blue_y, 2));
            
            if(blue_final > 255.0)
            {
                blue_final = 255.0;
            }
            red_final = sqrt(pow(red_x, 2) + pow(red_y, 2));
            if(red_final > 255.0)
            {
                red_final = 255.0;
            }
            green_final = sqrt(pow(green_x, 2) + pow(green_y, 2));
            if(green_final > 255.0)
            {
                green_final = 255.0;
            }

            edged[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_final);
            edged[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_final);
            edged[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_final);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = edged[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Where do you free your allocated memory?

Comment: Not related to the problem but there is no need for your `edged` array. You already copy the initial image before doing the calculations. Then you can directly store the result in `image`.

Comment: yeah  you are right   i need to free the memory and no need for the edged ..  great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to create an array that holds more than `width*hight` elements:

```c
    RGBTRIPLE(*larger_image)[width] = calloc(height + 2, (width + 2) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

This allocation may hold enough memory for this purpose but it does not match with the type of your variable.

`larger_image` is a pointer to an array of `width` elements, no matter how much memory you allocate.

Your runtime check detects that you access index `width+1` and prints an error.

To make it work you need to use

```c
    RGBTRIPLE(*larger_image)[width+2] = calloc(height + 2, (width + 2) * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```